# When to redraw screen in Jetpack Compose

Tags: android, animation, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack-compose-canvas

I have created raining animation using [Sketch](https://github.com/drinkthestars/composable-sheep-sketches/blob/main/canvasSketch/src/main/java/com/canvas/sketch/Sketch.kt#L157). The rain is then draw using this code with drawLine() with shift Offset. RaindropList is list of multiple generated raindrops with different starting coordinates.

```
Sketch(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
   speed = 1f, onDraw = { time ->
    val advance = abs(time - lastTime)

    raindropList.forEach { raindrop ->
    drawRaindropLine(
        raindrop = raindrop,
        raindropSpeed = advance * 20000, // shift Offset
    )
   }
  lastTime = time
 }
)
```

Shift offset and drawLine() inside drawRaindropLine(). When raindrop is out off the screen coordinates are set to 0 again.

```
val shiftOffset = Offset(
    x = 0f,
    y = raindropSpeed
)

drawLine(
    color = Color.White,
    start = startOffset + shiftOffset,
    end = endOffset + shiftOffset
)
```

My question is if this is the good approach to this kind of animation where there are multiple items on the screen which needs to be redrawn. I have mainly concerns about performance and I had to add check if time difference/advance is too large in some cases which is never good sign. The big advantage is that there is simple way how to change animation speed or stop it.

Thanks

[image]